# Problems running parallel Cucumber tests from Maven in a Windows batch file

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a suite of Cucumber Selenium tests in a Maven project and have recently configured the surefire plugin to run my tests in parallel. This works fine by simply executing a command similar to this, where test.runner.directory is a property declared in the `pom.xml` to hold the value of the file path to my Cucumber test runners:

```
mvn -Dtest.runner.directory=mytestsrunnerdirectory clean test
```

Next, I wanted to write a Windows batch file to wrap this call. So this is my attempt at a `.bat` file, in which the file path to the test runners is passed in as a parameter:

```
set testrunnerdirectory=%1
echo Running Seleium tests with Maven.
call mvn -Dtest.runner.directory=%testrunnerdirectory% clean test
echo Maven build completed
```

When executed, this gets as far as successfully running my tests in parallel, but then the script simply hangs. I see all the output from the tests appearing in the window and I observe all tests successfully running and completing, but I never get a "Build Success" message and the script never gets as far as printing my final echo message. It simply hangs indefinitely after the final test completes.

Interestingly, If I set `test.runner.directory` to a directory with only a single test runner in it, everything works fine (obviously this only launches a single test thread) and the script completes in its entirety. But it seems that the launching of multiple threads somehow throws it and at some point focus cannot be returned to the original command window.

As ever, I would be extremely grateful for any thoughts/advice. Thank you.

Comment: Cucumber tests are by my knowledge integration tests which means usually you can't run them in parallel...the question is why are the test hanging?

Comment: Any chance parallel test runners are trying to write to a single report file after the conclusion of tests?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Just to clarify, when I call maven direct from the command line i.e. not through my batch script, all the tests run in parallel and complete successfully. I only experience this hanging when i attempt to do the maven call from a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

I got round this issue by using a plugin in my `pom.xml`: `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin`

Originally, I had tried to configure surefire to run Test Runners that I had written myself, as per the snippet below: -

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>*TestRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

As per my original question, this ran my tests OK, but caused my batch script to hang and never complete. The new approach using `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` is shown in the snippets below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateRunners</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <glue>mystepdefinitionspackage</glue>
                        <featuresDirectory>myfeatures</featuresDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutputDir>myoutput</cucumberOutputDir>
                        <format>json,html</format>
                        <tags>"@MyTag"</tags>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This plugin generates Test Runners on the fly, and surefire just needs to be configured to pick up those generated Test Runners:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>10</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This worked brilliantly. My tests run in parallel and the script completes gracefully without hanging. Thank you for your interest in my question.